# Possible to implement a "job" pattern with GraphQL

Tags: graphql

Is there a reasonable way to implement a job-based query paradigm in GraphQL?

In particular, something like the following:

- Caller submits a search request
- Backend returns a job ID
- Caller receives status updates on the job as it runs
- Caller separately can retrieve pages of data from the job results

I guess the problem I see here is that we are splitting up the process into two steps: One is making the request and the second is retrieving data. As a result, the fields requested in the first request do not correspond with what is returned (just a job ID). And similarly, a call to retrieve results has the same issue.

Subscriptions don't really solve this problem either, I don't believe. They might help with requesting data that might take a long time to return I think, but that isn't quite the same as a job-based API.

Maybe this is a niche use case, and I have no doubt that it wasn't what GraphQL was initially built to solve. But, I'm just wondering if this is something doable, or if this is more of trying to fit a square peg into a round hole.

Comment: IMHO it can be easily done with subscriptions ... I used them to get notifications on [external] DB insertions, can be used for chats ... what's the problem? don't like graphql... go with rest/polling/whatever if you like

Comment: I like GraphQL, which is why I'm asking. I know how I would do this with it, but it's often preferable to use something standardized, if possible. A back and forth chat isn't quite the same as a Job-based API, so it's not clear how that would meet the described needs.

Comment: subscriptions covers many (all above) use cases ... no specialized for jobs (not needed?)

Comment: @xadm OK. My question was asking how. I know there isn't some built in "job" support. I was asking how one could reasonable build that pattern.

Comment: I think subscriptions are very close to what you want. Maybe you think subscriptions are "live queries". Rad [this article](https://medium.com/open-graphql/graphql-subscriptions-vs-live-queries-e38302c7ab8e) for a comparison. Be aware that live queries are neither standardised nor implemented by any server implementation yet and rather a concept.